# ¿Como guardar dos objetos diferentes enviados por una misma ruta hacia la api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor

hola comunidad tengo dos clases una llamada `impuesto` y otra llamada `impuestodetalle`, he creado una especie de formulario que no funciona como tal ya que no uso `editform` propio de `blazor` en ese formulario tengo los input a llenar y en sus `bind-value` los valores a enviar a la bd. El detalle esta en que en el formulario unos valores vienen de la clase impuesto y otros de la clase impuestodetalle entonces no se como pasarle el objeto a la ruta que va hacia el controlador ya que solo acepta uno y no dos y quiero enviar los datos todos juntos y llenar la tabla impuesto y la tabla impuestodetalle de la base de datos al mismo tiempo.

estas son las clases:

```
public class Impuesto
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ImpuestoId { get; set; }  
        public  ICollection<ImpuestoDetalle> ImpuestosDetalle { get; set; } 
        
        public string ClaveProdServ { get; set; }  
        public string ClaveUnidad { get; set; } 
    }
    public class ImpuestoDetalle
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ImpuestoDetalleId { get; set; }
        public TipoImpuesto TipoImpuesto { get; set; }
        public EfectoImpuesto EfectoImpuesto { get; set; }
        public decimal Tasa { get; set; } 
    }
```

en el formulario unos valores vienen  de impuesto:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" @bind-value="@Impuesto.ClaveProdServ" />
```

otros valores vienen  de impuestodetalle:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" @bind-value="@ImpuestoDetalle.Tasa" />
```

y así guardo los datos del formulario pero solo van los valores de la clase impuesto hacia la tabla impuesto me faltan los valores de la clase impuestodetalles:

```
@code {
    private Impuesto Impuesto = new Impuesto();    
    private ImpuestoDetalle ImpuestoDetalle = new ImpuestoDetalle();    

    public async Task GuardarImpuesto()
    {    
        var httpResponse = await repositorio.Post("api/Impuesto", Impuesto);
        @if (httpResponse.Error)
        {
            var body = await httpResponse.GetBody();
            await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeError(body);
        }
        else
        {
            await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeExitoso("Impuesto Agregado");
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/formulario-impuesto");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Son dos objetos diferentes : S, solo estas enviando Impuesto.

Comment: si así es , mi duda es como puedo enviar ambos al mismo tiempo y por una misma ruta hacia el controlador o como se puede manejar este tipo de situaciones cuando en un formulario tienes que usar dos clases

Comment: Como prueba de concepto puedes agregar el objeto ImpuestoDetalle a la lista de ImpuestosDetalle del objeto impuesto, en resumen (Envias 1 solo objeto que contiene ambos). para atar la lista al html es otra cosa, no me manejo con blazor, pero con razor se hace con un for en el html

Comment: a que se refiere con agregar el objeto ImpuestoDetalle a la lista de ImpuestosDetalle del objeto impuesto?

Answer (score 0):

A esto me refería:

```
@code {
    private Impuesto Impuesto = new Impuesto();    
    private ImpuestoDetalle ImpuestoDetalle = new ImpuestoDetalle();    

    public async Task GuardarImpuesto()
    {    
        //Aca podrias ponerlo antes de enviar
        Impuesto.ImpuestosDetalle = new List<ImpuestoDetalle>();
        Impuesto.ImpuestosDetalle.Add(ImpuestoDetalle);
 
        var httpResponse = await repositorio.Post("api/Impuesto", Impuesto);
        @if (httpResponse.Error)
        {
            var body = await httpResponse.GetBody();
            await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeError(body);
        }
        else
        {
            await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeExitoso("Impuesto Agregado");
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/formulario-impuesto");
        }
    }
}
```